# Dynamically Update a Form in Django AFTER Initial Creation/Display

Tags: django, validation, forms, dynamic

Is there away to dynamically modify and validate a Django form AFTER it's been created and displayed.(I have found a few snippets that show dynamic form creation, but these require that the dynamic fields are known/defined prior to creating the form.) My requirement is different.

Use Case:
I have a form where I want to display and validate additional input fields based on the selection from a dropdown on the initial form.  Based on the selection additional fields are 1) added and 2)must then be validated with appropriate error handling.

(In case you are wondering the data elements to be added are a set of name/value pairs stored in csv format in the model, but when displayed they are shown as separate input fields - the input data will be converted to a csv string prior to saving).

I got this partially working using ajax to dynamically add the additional fields to a template, but have not found a way to validate these new fields. I'm not  sure if this is a workable approach. I could probably do this in the browser using javascript, but would prefer a Django/server side solution.

Answer (score 1):

OK - So none responded to my question so far. However I did a bit more googling and found an excellent article that describe the solution I was looking for. Major Kudo's to the author of this blog.

[Create a Django Dynamic Form with JQuery - Dynamic Field Addition and Removal](http://dewful.com/?p=100)